# Number of zeros of $ f^n $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be infinetly differentiable function that vanishes at $10$ distinct points in $\Bbb R$.suppose $ f^{n} $ denote $n$-th derivate of $f$, for $n \ge 1$. Then which of following is true.

1. $ f^n $ has atleast $10$ zeros, for $1\le n\le8$
2. $ f^n $ has atleast $1$ zero, for $1\le n\le9$
3. $ f^n $ has atleast $10$ zeros, for $ n\ge10$
4. $ f^n $ has atleast $1$ zeros, for $ n\ge9$

I am still finding a way to begin.correct answer is $2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** if $f(x) = 0$ for $10$ distinct $x \in \Bbb R$, how many zeros must $f'(x)$ have by Rolle's theorem?  If $f'(x)$ has at least *that number* of zeros, how many zeros must $f''(x)$ have?

Comment: I only know that between two zeros of f, there lies a root of derivative

Comment: Yes... between any two consecutive roots.  How many such pairs are there?

Comment: 9th derivative will have only 1 root , what next?

Comment: You mean... the 9th derivative will have "at least one root".

Comment: How to eliminate option 4?

Comment: Use a suitable polynomial (see Hagen's) as a counterexample

Answer (score 2):

1. Consider $f(x)=x(x-1)\cdots(x-9)$, for which $f^{(8)}$ is a polynomial of degree $2$.
2. Use Rolle's theorem to show that $f^{(n)}$ has at least $10-n$ distict real roots.
3. Consider $f(x)=x(x-1)\cdots(x-9)$, for which $f^{(10)}$  is a nonzero constant
4. ditto